# Laravel 5 Controller from a Different namespace

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to load controller that resides inside a package.
Package itself is on the root level in a folder like /packages/my/ ...
The package structure is like this:

```
/packages/my/framework/src/My/Controllers/PageController.php
```

Frist in my RouteServiceProvider:

```
  $router->group(['namespace' => 'My\Controllers'], function($router)
        {
            require "...../routes.php";
   });
```

in the composer.json in the root of laravel

```
 "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/", 
            "My\\": "packages/my/framework/src"
        }
```

then composer dump-autoload , i can see its been added to autoload_psr4.php 
the actual controller

```
<?php
namespace My\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers;

class PageController extends Controllers\Controller { .... }
```

But I am getting ReflectionException that the class does not exist. Obviously the routing part works, why it can't see the Controller?
Thanks!

Comment: This is for Laravel 5

Comment: Namespace conflict with double Controllers, maybe? Try `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` and then just `extends Controller`.

Comment: nope, same thing, there might be other problems later, but for right now it can't find the class itself .. which is the weird part.

Comment: That sucks. :/ Hope somebody else gives an easy answer, I have no idea. good luck

Answer (score 0):

closing my own question .. I was missing the root namespace in the psr-4 loader .. packages/my/framework/src/**My**